# How to enter or go to the next page in JSF flow

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, faces-flow

In normal way to enter to flow or go from some page to next page in flow we use

```
   <h:commandButton> or <h:commandLink>
```

But how is it possible to enter to flow or go to the next page in flow (if we currently are in flow)  from backing bean?

I try to dispatch from faces context but it doesn't work.  Do you know how to do it?

I use only viewnode pages. I configure a flow using a

```
      @FlowDefinition
      @Producent
      @Flowdefinition
               public Flow defineFlow(@FlowbuilderParameter FlowBuilder FlowBuilder){ 
     flowBuilder.id("","registerFlow");
          flowBuilder.viewNode("registerStart","/faces/start.xhtm").Markasstartnode();
flowBuilder.viewNode("step2","/faces/step2.xhtm");
     …
     }
```

And now i would enter to flow from backing bean. Something like

```
      FacesContext.getCurrenInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("registerFlow");
```

I think possible i have to use FlowHandler from context

```
   FlowHandler handler = FacesContext.getApplication().getFlowHandler();
   handler.transition(); // and what next?

    how here i can redirect user to some viewnode of flow?
```

Comment: It depends. You need to provide more info in order we can help you. What type of flow are you using: view nodes, method call, ...? Can you provide what configuration do you have?

Comment: Regardless of the problem and solution, never use `ExternalContext#dispatch()`. That method is a leftover from JSF 1.x and should never have existed in JSF.

Comment: But i still dont know how i can navigate through flow under backing bean. I know how to do it in jsf view but not in backing bean